# Comment construire « faire confiance de »

Tags: grammaire, verbes

En considérant le verbe « faire confiance de », quelle phrase est correcte ?
J'aimerais savoir quelle construction est correcte.

- C'est à quoi on peut faire confiance.
- C'est ce dont on peut faire confiance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On utilise « faire confiance **à** quelqu’un »

« *<strike>Faire confiance *de* quelqu’un</strike> » est incorrect et à proscrire.

J’éviterais cependant d’utiliser « faire confiance à *quelque chose* » (on fait en général confiance à *une personne*). Si tu veux parler d’une chose ou d’un événement, je privilégierais « avoir confiance en *quelque chose* » (que l’on peut d’ailleurs utiliser avec une personne également).

Dans ton cas, je dirai donc plutôt « C’est ce en quoi on peut avoir confiance ».

Comment: merci de votre attention